# Can't get rpi camera module v3 working on my rpi 0w

Tags: pi-zero, raspicam, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, libcamera

Is there a specific command that can tell if I even connected the camera CORRECTLY to my rpi (so hardware issue can be ruled out)?

Using this command it seems the rpi is detecting the camera on Raspbian (bullseye).
`vcgencmd get_camera` returns
`supported=1 detected=1, libcamera interfaces=0`

The version of my camera is

```
vcgencmd version
Oct 17 2023 15:43:26
Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom                                        
version 30f0c5e4d076da3ab4f341d88e7d505760b93ad7 (clean) (release) (start_x)
```

I've tried both raspistill and libcamera-hello commands and even with python code

```
from picamera import PiCamera
camera = PiCamera()
```

and im getting error messages like this:

*mmal: mmal_vc_port_enable: failed to enable port vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV): ENOSPC
mmal: mmal_port_enable: failed to enable connected port (vc.null_sink:in:0(OPQV))0x226f390 (ENOSPC)
mmal: mmal_connection_enable: output port couldn't be enabled*

Where do i even start to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Use `libcamera-hello --list-cameras` that will give details of the cameras it can see. Also remove any parms from `config.txt` except `camera_auto_detect=1` unless you have a camera listed at https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/camera_software.html